# WPF Clear Region on a Drawing Context?

Tags: wpf, drawingcontext

So I am producing a transparent PNG using a DrawingContext and DrawingVisual.

Inside the DrawingContext, I drew a rectange.

I would now like to "cut out" a circle inside of the rectangle. How do I do this? I did not find any functions in drawing context to clear a region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using **[CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx)** to combine 2 geometries (each time). It has `GeometryCombineMode` allowing you to specify some logic combination. In this case what you need is `GeometryCombineMode.Xor`. The intersection of the Rect and the Ellipse (cirlce) will be *cut out*. Here is the simple code demonstrating it:

```
DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen()) {                    
  var rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);        
  var cb = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Xor, 
                                new RectangleGeometry(rect),
                               new EllipseGeometry(new Point(150, 100), 50, 50));
  dc.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Blue, null, cb);                    
}
```

I hope you know how to render the `DrawingVisual`. You can use some `RenderTargetBitmap` to capture it into some kind of BitmapSource and then you have many ways to show this bitmap.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The Black region means the color is transparent.

In case you want to cut out some complex image (such as drawn text or image). You can turn the `CombinedGeometry` into some kind of `OpacityMask` (type of `Brush`). We can turn it into a `DrawingBrush` and this brush can be used as `OpacityMask` which can be passed into `DrawingContext.PushOpacityMask` method:

```
DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();                
using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen()) {                    
  var rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
  var cb = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Xor, 
                                new RectangleGeometry(rect),
                               new EllipseGeometry(new Point(150, 100), 50, 50));
  var mask = new DrawingBrush(new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Blue, null, cb));      
  dc.PushOpacityMask(mask);
  dc.DrawImage(someImage, rect);
  dc.DrawText(new FormattedText("Windows Presentation Foundation", 
                                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                 System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                 new Typeface("Lucida Bright"), 30, Brushes.Red){ 
                                   MaxTextWidth = rect.Width, 
                                   MaxTextHeight = rect.Height, 
                                   TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                                 }, new Point());
}
```

[image]

Note that the `rect` should have the size of your whole drawing. Then positioning the *hole* and other drawn stuff will be exact as what you want.

Finally the `DrawingVisual` also has a useful property called `Clip` which is a `Geometry`. So you can prepare some `CombinedGeometry` and assign it to `DrawingVisual.Clip` property.

Suppose you already have your `DrawingVisual` (with some drawn stuff including text, images, ...). The following code will *punch* a hole through it:

```
//prepare the geometry, which can be considered as the puncher.
var rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
var cb = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Xor, 
                              new RectangleGeometry(rect),
                             new EllipseGeometry(new Point(150, 100), 50, 50));
//punch the DrawingVisual
yourDrawingVisual.Clip = cb;
```

Comment: Okay... simple enough... however, I have another complication. What if instead of cutting a drawn circle out of a drawn rectangle, I want to cut out of a drawn text?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod see my update. The only thing I could think of is using some `OpacityMask`.